# iOS custom navigationBar button item

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I would like to set navBar buttons like safari as following image shows. However I can only set a custom image for toolbar button but square button container remains although I set plain style. How to reach it? Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Plain` is only for tool bars not nav bars, that's the only way you can achieve no border. You must use a custom UIButton on your navbar to achieve the same results.

If you need an icon somewhat like that, you can check on [Default Icon](http://defaulticon.com)

Answer (score 0):

Use UIBarButtonItem method for creating bar button

```
- (id)initWithCustomView:(UIView *)customView;
```

and create custom view with UIButton of type UIButtonTypeCustom